# laravel many to many relation additional foreign key.?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

i'm trying to get extra column as foreign key in laravel many to many relationship..here is my table structure

```
idcards 
   id,
   name,
quality
   id,
   name
idcard_quality
  id,
  idcard_id
  quality_id
  related_id
```

in above idcard_quality table i want add extra foreign key related_id, i wanted to retrieve result like every idcard hasmany qualities and that quality is another idcard.. suppose one idcardcard has one normal quality and that normal quality is different idcard... 
please help me

Answer (score 0):

I think your table design should look like this:

`idcards 
   id,
   name
quality
   id,
   name,
   related_id
idcard_quality
  idcard_id
  quality_id`

This way when you retrieve the values of the parent/related id card on joining the tables.

Comment: i have only 4 qualities and 5k cards i think that table design won't work.. i want related_id as foreign key of idcards table..like own table foreign key in many to many relationship..

Comment: Your original question and the comment here are contradicting. The design you have listed in original question doesn't follow the many-to-many normalization. Your design should always take into account only the relation between the entities, not the amount records. So, please provide your expectation clearly with some sample data that anyone could assist you.